# Creating Editor in wxWidget with Line Numbers

Tags: c++, c++11, wxwidgets

As part of a project at work I have build an editor in C++ using wxWidgets (unfortunately it's very specific so I can't use an existing one).  I would like to have it so that when you move to the next line you get a line count (see screenshot.

What do I need to do in wxWidget to achieve this please?  For editing I have been using a large edit box.

Thank you in advance.

[image: as per]

Comment: Is the question how to create the GUI element which shows the line numbers (the gray part in the screenshot)? That is not entirely clear atm.

Comment: @kalj Hi, yes it's how to create the (wxWidget) GUI element, or just explain what elements/methods I need.  The screenshot is an example of a generic editor with line numbers as an example of what I am looking at doing.

Comment: Okay. I'm no expert on the matter, but I would imagine making an array of labels which is as long as the current number of lines, which is then packed into some container resulting in a column like that. You probably need some sort of callback which updates the line numbers each time the number of lines in the textbox changes.

Comment: This might also be something to look into: http://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.1/group__group__class__stc.html Apparently a whole text editor framework inside wxWidget.

Comment: @PaulMorriss, or check wxRichTextCtrl in addition to wxSTC.

Comment: There are already answers in the comments here, so I won't give my own but, basically, if you need an editor for anything like computer programs/code, use `wxStyleTextCtrl`. If you need a generic word-processing like editor, use `wxRichTextCtrl`.